# How to filter related contacts list based on account selection from dropdown?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, picklist, dependent-picklist

[image]

I'm trying to display related contacts list in dropdown based on particular account selected from account dropdown.

I can able to display all accounts in dropdown but after selecting an acount how to filter contacts list related to that account.

### Component:

```
                <aura:component controller="AccountDropdown">
                    <!--Declare Event Handlers--> 
                     <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>  
                    <!--  <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit1}" value="{!this}"/> -->
                    <!--Declare Attributes-->
                     <aura:attribute name="accountslist" type="list" />
                     <aura:attribute name="contactslist" type="list" />
                     <aura:attribute name="inputAccount" type ="String"/>

                     <ui:inputSelect label = "Account">
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.accountslist}" var="acc">
                               <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!acc.Name}" label="{!acc.Name}" aura:id="inputAccount" />
                        </aura:iteration>
                     </ui:inputSelect> 
                    <br/>
                    <lightning:button label="Submit" class="slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.processRelatedContacts }" /><br/><br/>
                     <ui:inputSelect label = "Contacts">
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactslist}" var="con">
                               <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!con.Name}" label="{!con.Name}"/>
                        </aura:iteration>
                     </ui:inputSelect>     
                 </aura:component>
```

### Controller .js

```
    ({
      doInit: function(component, evt, helper) {

         var action = component.get("c.getAccountList");
         action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
         component.set("v.accountslist", response.getReturnValue());

        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
      },
        //Process the selected account
        processRelatedContacts: function(component, event, helper) {
         var action = component.get("c.getContactList");
         var inputId = component.find("inputAccount").get("v.value").id;  
         action.setParams({

             "accountId" : inputId

            });

         action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
         component.set("v.contactslist", response.getReturnValue());

        });
      }

    })
```

### Apex Class

```
    public class AccountDropdown {

        public String accountId{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        Public static List<Account> getAccountList(){
            //get all accounts list
            List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];
            return accList;
        }    
        @AuraEnabled
        Public static List<Contact> getContactList(String accountId){
            //get all contacts list
            List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE id = : accountId];
            return conList;
        }   
    }
```

Please anyone suggest some ideas to achieve this

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the error raised?

Comment: @MartinLezer please check the above screenshot with error details I attached.

Comment: you miss the `$A.enqueueAction(action)` on `processRelatedContacts()`

Comment: Thanks Martin it works.One small thing without clicking the button how  can i automatically populate related contacts after selecting account

Comment: @Raj did you add `$A.enqueueAction(action) on processRelatedContacts()`

Comment: @Sarvesh Thanks it works.Now I can able to get the contacts list but here the problem is I'm not getting related contacts list.After clicking the button It displays few contacts as fixed,If select any Account.Related contact list doesn't change.